# mainloop function from turtle class is not working, Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-2.x, python-turtle

This is my code :

```
import turtle             
wn = turtle.Screen()      
alex = turtle.Turtle()    

alex.forward(50)          
alex.left(90)             
alex.forward(30)          

wn.mainloop()
```

And my error is: "_Screen object has no attribute mainloop"

I tried to do just "mainloop" but then I got NameError while doing alex.mainloop gave same error i.e. turtle object has no attribute mainloop.

Googling told me that I might have my file name as turtle.py creating the conflict but that's not the case.

Comment: In python 3, this works fine, so I assume this is py 2 only. I'm tagging as such but please let me know if I'm mistaken in that assumption.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: '\_Screen' object has no attribute 'mainloop'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832015/attributeerror-screen-object-has-no-attribute-mainloop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `mainloop()` function on the `turtle` module.  So your last line should be:

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I don't understand, why won't it work on the screen or turtle object?

Comment: It is very unclear from the documentation.  The documentation of `turtle.mainloop()` has an example showing `screen.mainloop()`.